# Making development patterns more efficient with ZSH

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, shell

A common pattern I find myself encountering is converting a CSV to a projected GeoJSON as described [here](https://gist.github.com/jacquestardie/6211044).

That entails 3 steps, and I'd like to get it down to the following:

```
GEOIFY {file} {originalProjection} {newProjection} =
    csv2geojon {file.csv} > {file.geojson} &&
    ogr2ogr 
        -F geojson 
        -s_srs epsg:{originalProjection} 
        -t_srs epsg:{newProjection}
        {reprojectedFile.geojson} {file.geojson}
```

If anyone has any good resources on how to create functions and use variables with ZSH (which is what I think I need to do this) that would be beautiful. I must be using the wrong vocabulary, because my googling hasn't yielded anything so far.

*As always, thanks!*

Comment: couldn't you just use ogr2ogr - http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_csv.html

Comment: If it supports moving from a CSV with XY values in EPSG:26919 to a GeoJSON projected in EPSG:4326, then yes. I'd had trouble getting this to work before, and csv2geojson did the job, so, that's how that happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a shell script:

```
#!/bin/zsh 
# note: script also works in bash which I think 
# is the default shell in OSX as well as Linux
# so you could use #!/bin/bash instead if you prefer

usage(){
    usage="$0 infilepath {-o originalProjection} {-n newProjection}"
    if [ ! -z "$1" ];then # Was there an additional message?
        echo $1
    fi
    echo "Usage: $usage"
    exit 1
}

orig_proj="some EPSG code"
new_proj="another EPSG code"

if [ -z "$1" ];then                           # Is filepath zero length?
    usage "Error: Filepath is required"
else
    case ${1} in
        -o) usage "Error: Filepath is required";;
        -n) usage "Error: Filepath is required";;
        -h) usage;;
    esac
    filepath=$1
fi

shift #Get rid of $1 so getopts picks up the other parameters
while getopts ':o:n:h' arg
do
    case ${arg} in
        o) orig_proj=${OPTARG};;
        n) new_proj=${OPTARG};;
        h) usage;;
    esac
done

csv2geojon $filepath > ${filepath%.*}.geojson #the %.* bit strips off the file ext.
ogr2ogr -F geojson -s_srs epsg:$orig_proj -t_srs epsg:$new_proj \
     ${filepath%.*}_$new_proj.geojson ${filepath%.*}.geojson
```

If the script is called "geoify" and is executable, you can just use: `./geoify /data/some.csv` or `./geoify /data/some.csv -o 1234 -n 2345` if you're in the same directory as the script. Or you can copy it somewhere in your $PATH and call `geoify /data/some.csv etc...`

Comment: Thanks Luke. I'm a shell scripting noob, so this will take me a bit to wrap my head around, but it looks to do what I was intending.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Could be improved, but this works for meow.

```
geoify() {
    csv2geojson $1 > output.geojson && \
    ogr2ogr -F geojson -s_srs epsg:$2 -t_srs epsg:$3 projected.geojson output.geojson;
}
```

Next step is to figure out how to set defaults for $2 and $3 if I leave them undefined.